# How fast an implementation of KMeans clustering on an FPGA board can get?

Tags: image-processing, vhdl, k-means, fpga

I wrote a code in OpenCV/C++ that segments the RGB images of a video: I load the image and I cluster areas within it based on its colours.I chose KMeans to perform the segmentation and the results are good. However, with images of size 960x1280 it takes several seconds to do the clustering of a single image, and at this rate I can't use it in real time. My code is meant to be rewritten in VHDL in order to be run on an FPGA board in real time, so I wonder, given the parallelization capabilities of modern FPGA boards, how much acceleration can I get? I have little experience with such boards so I can't predict how fast my code can get if implemented on one of them. I want to have your opinions, maybe I will have to change Kmeans with some other image segmentation algorithm if the acceleration is not enough, and if so, it's better to do it now rahter than after having written the vhdl version.

Comment: If you have a little bit of experience  don't do it ! and here ist why. yes FPGA is pretty fast, but are able to sythesis a KMean on it(let say of course u're), what about OpenCV part? where do you plan to run it ? think about the speed of the buses! my take on this try to use GPU there definitly easier and simpler to use comparing to FPGA, and perfom pretty well in image processing. PS[ u mentioned real time, I guess you mean just streaming] if it not the case you have to get rif of openCV and get  real time lib. By the way put some code to your question maybe the prob is the coding ;-)

Comment: @Engine, OpenCV is not an issue, the source code of Opencv is available online and it's not that difficult to rewrite it in C or C++ independently from OpenCV, maybe it won't be as optimized as OpenCV, but with additional effort, you can reach a decent execution time using SIMD and OpenMP routines. By real time I mean that while the camera is on, I sample the 'live' stream with a certain frequency and cluster each image as it arrives. Can you elaborate your answer a little bit regarding "the synthesis of KMeans on the board".

Comment: The synthesis of KMeans mean putting everything in vhdl, and since u think opencv wouldn't be an issue  where do you want to do the processing on the Hard- or softcore ? my  1st choice is denfinitly a GPU.  It fast enough to solve your problem but if u have the money and specially enough time to do  this on FPGA that a call u should make :)

Comment: @Engine, actually before I decide on whether to implement it on an FPGA or on a GPU, I should probably make a tradeoff study. For the time being I have no idea where to start from, but thanks for your advice. If you have any other advice or opinion they're always welcome

Comment: It all depends on your budget. FPGA (as storage components, this unusable without pcb with boot ROM power supply etc) start at a few dollar and go up to 50k dollar. And for the top tier you even have boards with multiple of these FPGAs (used for ASIC prototyping).  GPUs are definitely much cheaper per FLOP and **MUCH MUCH** easier to program. And what do you mean with real time?

Comment: @JHBonarius By real time I mean that I have to respect delay constraints between the acquisition of the image by the camera and the segmentation of the image.

Comment: K-means looks like a memory intensive algorithm. FPGAs only have limited internal memory, so you will probably be limited by the bandwidth of the external memory in both implementations. GPU, especially with HBM, is probably fastest there.

Comment: Your question is unanswerable. Profile your code, and find out why it takes several seconds. Find out whether it can be parallelised - at the simplest level, can you process sub-blocks independently? Prove it by writing the code to distribute the blocks and stitch the results. Or can you run several calculations in parallel in a single block? What calculations? When you've found out, post the algorithm and you might get an answer.

Comment: @EML, that's just what I should be doing! thank you very much